# How to extract all rows from excel data set when cell/column contains certain text

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel data-set that contains more columns and rows than I need in my final table.  I would like to extract the rows that contain the word "Domestic" in it into a new table.
For example, I have 6 columns of data (A, B, C, D, E, F) and column "F" is where the word "Domestic" would be if the cell contains it.  I would then like to bring back columns A, C, and D for all rows where column F contains "Domestic" - and if the row does not contain "Domestic" it is ignored. My headers is in row 1 and my data runs from row 2-5500. 
Can someone please help me with a formula or exact VBA code that would do this in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Using an array formula, like so, having data in a1:f21, drag down and across from I1

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$F$21,SMALL(IF($F$1:$F$21="domestic",ROW($F$1:$F$21)),ROWS($I$1:$I1)),COLUMNS($I$1:I$1)),"")
```

Comment: Thank you Nate -- what would row "I" be?  In this part of the formula:("ROWS($I$1:$I1)),COLUMNS($I$1:I$1)))

Comment: It counts the rows in a selection, so it increments by 1 each time, as the columns, so you are changing the index point with the rows, and the index column with the columns.  Row is k of the small function and columns is column of the index function

Comment: But I don't have any data in row I -- does that matter?

Comment: no, it's not doing counta or count, its Rows() which returns a count of the rows.  Try it, =rows(qq1:qq100) will give you 100, I is simply chosen, as it's where I've put my 1st formula

Comment: Thanks - I am getting the header line returned but no data.

Comment: have you added as an array, CTRL SHIFT ENTER>

Comment: Hi Nathan - you're right, i wasn't added it as an array!  But two things: 1) this is dropping my last row of data that it should be including (as it contains "domestic".  I do have a header row in the table I am inputting the extracted data - does that matter?
Also, Is there a way where I can only bring back certain columns instead of all of them?  I would want columns A, C, D, and E.  And I would want the order of them to be A, E, C, D -- is this possible?

Comment: You need to change to be $2$ where I have $1$ I think.  The 2nd part, change the columns(I:I) bit to be 1 for a, 2 for b, 3 for c etc.